# Async/await in azure worker role causing the role to recycle

Tags: azure, async-await

I am playing around with Tasks, Async and await in my WorkerRole (RoleEntryPoint).

I had some unexplained recycles and i have found out now that if something is running to long in a await call, the role recycles. To reproduce it, just do a await Task.Delay(60000) in the Run method.

Anyone who can explain to me why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Run` method *must* block. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx):

> If you do override the Run method, your code should block indefinitely. If the Run method returns, the role is automatically recycled by raising the Stopping event and calling the OnStop method so that your shutdown sequences may be executed before the role is taken offline.

A simple solution is to just do this:

```
public override void Run()
{
  RunAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task RunAsync()
{
  while (true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(60000);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext):

```
public override void Run()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    while (true)
    {
      await Task.Delay(60000);
    }
  });
}
```

Whichever option you choose, `Run` should *not* be `async`. It's kind of like `Main` for a Console app ([see my blog for why `async Main` is not allowed](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html)).

Comment: and if the run is async, it do not block indefinitely ? You solution will recycle after 60 secs as its shown in your answer right?

Comment: I updated my post to include a link to my blog on why `async Main` isn't allowed. `async Run` isn't allowed for the same reason. My example will recycle after 60 seconds because it returns from `Run`. If you don't want to recycle, don't return from `Run`.

Comment: Likely not a good idea in the general case, but if you want your Run to block indefinitely regardless of what happens with RunAsync() (or whatever other code it executes initially), you can always [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) with [Timeout.Infinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) :)

Comment: @Stehpen Just wondering if there's an updated version of this? I realise that Azure Worker Roles haven't moved on much, but the advice might of.

Comment: @matt_lethargic: I don't know; I haven't used Azure Worker Roles ever since Azure Functions came out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a lower value for `Task.Delay` like 1000 (ms).  I suspect that the worker role cannot respond quickly enough to the health check.  The role is then considered unresponsive and restarted.

Make sure the `Run` method never returns with something like this

```
while (true)
{               
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Or with `Task.Delay` in your case.

Comment: Got any information on this health check? how long it can hang before. I am lowering it to 1000 ms, but just wondered what caused the issue when i had a long hanging async method. Its because i have a async method that set up some stuff on teh server that takes a few min. Awaiting it caused it to recycle, and no await it runs fine as the run method enters the while(true) loop.

Comment: I haven't that information from any official source unfortunately.  Anyone got an answer to that?