# async/await for Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous

I am creating an Worker.

Right now it uses a spin-lock.

I think there must be a better way to do it with `async/await`.

Ideally, I'd like to have my Worker wait on the queue until a message comes in, and then process it.

The `Run()` method is exactly like `Main()` ... in order to keep the worker alive, it cannot exit.

**My code today:**

```
public override void Run()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        Message msg = queue.GetMessage();
        if (msg != null) 
        {
            ProcessMessage(msg);
        }
        else 
        {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

Microsoft provides a `queue.GetMessageAsync()` method.

I tried `Message msg = await queue.GetMessageAsync();`

The problem is when I did this, I was forced to change the signature of the Run method to be:

```
public override async Task RunAsync()
```

This won't work because the worker has a very specific API and I need to have a `Run()` method with the exact signature.

Comment: What forced you to change the method signature?

Comment: @MarcGravell Do you mean because the `Run()` method has to not exit, that I'm better off not trying to make the internal guts of it Asynchronous?  Incidentally, this is an Azure Worker `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEntryPoint`.  Ideally, I'd like to have a worker just fire off when a message is dropped on the Queue, but I don't think that is supported.

Comment: You can either run your logic in a Task.Run(() =>{ while(true){ ...}}); or use the queue.GetMessageAsync().Result to run it synchronously

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand what you are saying now.  I found this based on what you were describing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991675/463196.  It looks like there is no advantage to me mixing "sync and async" as you said ... it just complicates the code. Could you please promote your comment to an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @RQuijano Read Stephen Cleary's blog and you will never do that again ;o)

Comment: @RQuijano the first example (`Task.Run`) illustrates "async over sync"; the second example (`.Result`) illustrates "sync over async". Both are very bad ideas in almost all cases.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm aware those are bad solutions but he did mention he couldn't change the API

Comment: @PhilipTenn are you trying to create an agent? .NET already has a message processing "agent" in the DataFlow library. ActionBlock<T> can process posted messages on a separate task, although your code doesn't need to know

Comment: @RQuijano given two bad options, and one status-quo that is OK (but doesn't use async): it is OK to choose the stratus-quo

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am coding against the Azure API.  Please see `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEntryPoint`

Comment: @PhilipTenn an ActionBlock can process incoming messages no matter where they come from. Your actual issue is that you need essentially an asynchronous enumerator, which isn't available *yet* in C# (it's part of CoreFX Lab). In a similar situation I used an F# helper to read and pump messages asynchronously using [asyncSeq](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/library/AsyncSeq.html) and pump them to an ActionBlock for farther processing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the point, though, is that this is a synchronous API; it is (from the question) [RoleEntryPoint.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx) - "If you do override the Run method, your code should block indefinitely. If the Run method returns, the role is automatically recycled..." - so you **cannot** do a meaningful async yield, which means you'd have to use "sync over async"; writing regular sync code would be preferable to "sync over async" Things like async enumerators are thus completely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API you're implementing is fundamentally synchronous, switching to `async` is not necessarily possible or desirable. You *can* do "sync over async", but that is an anti-pattern, and fundamentally you're not going to be achieving the intended "release the thread" if you do that - you'll just be adding lots of `async`/`await` machinery **without** getting the upsides. So: just stick synchrounous until an async API **from the caller** is available. Note: do **not** do `async void` - if you do that, the caller will think you've finished at the wrong time

Comment: Why not use an ActionBlock ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I fail to see how that would change anything in any useful way - feel free to suggest it with an example, though

Comment: And I seem to remember that Rx can be used to convert the asynchronous `ReceiveAsync` loop into a stream of events, suitable for posting to a block

Comment: You all keep in mind we are talking about an Azure Background Service?

Comment: @SirRufo any asynchronous service or library is exactly the same - it's just an asynchronous call. Whether you read a queue asynchronously or batched data asynchronously, it's the same. You need a way to enumerate asynchronously.

Comment: @MarcGravell the problem has two parts - asynchronously enumerate over the queue messages and process the retrieved messages. It's the async enumerator that's hard. F#'s `asyncSeq` provides this already and a small helper function in F# would probably be the best solution. CoreFX Lab has another implementation.  An ugly solution would be to use `Task.Run` to hold the loop. Or a custom ActionBlock could read messages asynchronously and post them to a target. All these techniques would need a way to stop the loop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, the problem has exactly one part: it is a fundamentally synchronous API, `RoleEntryPoint.Run`; you **cannot** do any kind of async here *unless* you force "sync over async", which would be adding overhead without being able to realize the advantages. There is *no purpose whatsoever* in adding any kind of async enumerator / sequence if we are **required** (by the API) to be synchronous. The only way to do `async` here would be for the tool to add a `protected virtual bool IsAsync {get;}` and a `protected virtual Task RunAsync()` pair, and make use of them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (responding to a now-deleted comment) that's the point: the service **does** expect `Run` to block; that's **exactly** what the API dictates, including the base implementation of `Run`. The point of `async` is to release the current thread for processing other things - if you have a thread stuck in `Run` (even if just the default "block forever" implementation), then you might as well have just used that thread to *do your actual work*, without adding all the async/await machinery (which doesn't come for free)

Comment: `The Run is considered the Main method for your application.` I'm using `asyncSeq` to retrieve air ticket audit reports that require multiple `getnext` commands in an asynchronous way, in a command-line worker. The last calls are `pipeline.Complete();pipeline.Completion.Wait();`. I don't think the OP would really care if `Run` blocked in this case, just as I don't care if `Main` blocks. I do want to retrieve and process thousands of ticket records in parallel, parse them and store them in a database

Comment: The only real difference is that I have a set number of dates to post to the pipeline while the OP needs to read data for as long as the service runs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but... regular `async`/`await` *isn't about* parallelism - it is about making a *single sequential flow* work in a continuation pattern, and thus *enable* fewer threads to process separate flows by making use of the blocked time - *if* you have a mechanism to add work to do (other flows) in that time. If you want to do parallelism, that remains available identically (including async) for both a sync or async root

Comment: @MarcGravell when I have to retrieve 1000 records per day, at 1 sec per record, I do want DOP>1 and async to avoid blocking and memory waste. It's not either or, all of these are combined. Plus, when I have to send multiple `GetNext` HTTP commands, I want them to be async since `GetStringAsync` is *already* async. I'd have to *block* to work in a different way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos great, then do that; but the OP *doesn't seem to have that need*, and has a perfectly viable synchronous API. There is literally **zero benefit** - in the OP's context - to adding any `async`. If you have a different context, then you may have different conclusions.